# Bayesian Classifier to predict a class probability?

Tags: regression, bayesian, numerical-models

I have a 2 input (independent) variables:

```
1) number of likes (numeric value between 0 and 99)
2) number of dislikes (numeric value between 0 and 99)
```

and I would like to predict a class ('class'), from which we have a finite pre-defined set (e.g. A1-A5) but also its probability or likelyhood ('prob'). Here an example of the output that I would like get, "output" is the dependent variable:

```
like     dislike     class     prob
------------------------------------
5         2          A1        0.3
10        10         A3        0.5
99        1          A2        1.0
```

What is the best method given that I do not have much training data (e.g. 1000 cases) ?